# Why $\rm He^{++}$ is more opaque than $\rm He^{+}$ and so absorbs more energy?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics, astrophysics, astronomy, stars

In the Cepheids, $\rm He^{++}$ is more opaque than $\rm He^{+}$ so it absorbs more energy.

If it is because a more charged particle have a higher electromagnetic field and the stronger the field, the more the photon will interact with it. How can we explain that formally (perhaps with Feynman diagram if required)?

Comment: I don't think He++ is absorbing too many photons itself, unless they are gammas. So, what is left?

Answer (score 2):

I dispute your claim. Doubly ionised He is comparatively transparent. The mechanism that excites Cepheid pulsations is the high opacity of partially ionised He.

Normally the opacity increases with density and decreases with temperature in stellar interiors. The dependence on temperature dominates and thus when a layer is compressed, the opacity decreases and allows heat to escape. In a partially ionised He layer this does not happen. On compression, such a layer becomes more opaque due to increasing density and because of photoionisation which allows the compression to occur without a big rise in temperature. Or in other words, the opacity increases as the temperature increases. This traps heat by ionising the He. The heat is then released as the layer expands and cools. Once He is mostly doubly ionised, then this mechanism no longer works.

I guess you are getting your information from Wikipedia. I'm afraid it is wrong on this. Try these lecture notes by the colossus of stellar radiation hydrodynamics - [Mihalas](http://permalink.lanl.gov/object/tr?what=info:lanl-repo/lareport/LA-UR-01-5586). The relevant bit is the first paragraph of section 3.

Comment: Thanks for your explain. I had also readed it [here](http://agiamman.web.cern.ch/agiamman/astro/astro5.pdf) on slide 9. Your link to the lecture notes doesn't work (error message : "This service is unavailable."). Have you any other link to it?

Comment: @Lery_Phys I think that's fixed it.

Comment: The lecture notes explain the pulsation mechanism. But not so well what I want to know. So I try a explain : $\rm He^{+}$ is more opaque than $\rm He^{++}$ because a gas of $\rm He^{+}$ is more dense than a gas of $\rm He^{++}$ (if we consider same pressure and quantity). This is due to the fact that Coulomb repulsion between atoms of $\rm He^{++}$ is higher than between atoms of $\rm He^{+}$. Am I right ?

Comment: And more density leads to more diffusion which means more radiation trapped in stellar interiors.